# Spring Boot + Shiro

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, authorization, shiro

I want to implement Authorisation and Authentication with Shiro in my Spring boot application that I am developing from scratch. Presently, it just takes the username and password to check for correctness in DB. Can somebody help me to understand the implementation concept, like how to implement role based authorisation, in Spring Boot and authentication with Shiro and OAuth2 ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example: https://github.com/apache/shiro/tree/master/samples/spring-boot-web

For authz checks you can use annotations:
https://shiro.apache.org/java-authorization-guide.html#annotation-authorization

For OAuth, Shrio doesn't directly support OAuth yet, but there are a few thirdparty libs that add it, like Buji:
https://github.com/bujiio/buji-pac4j